# Why I get "implicit declaration of function 'PerformXMLXPathQuery'" warning?

Tags: iphone, ios, warnings

Why I get "implicit declaration of function 'PerformXMLXPathQuery'" warning?

```
NSString *response = [request responseString];  
NSString* xPathQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"//ExtendedData"];  
NSArray* myArray = PerformXMLXPathQuery([response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ],xPathQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning indicates that compiler cannot find a prototype declared for the  PerformXMLXPathQuery function. Check if you have imported the header file where your function was declared.

Comment: My appli worked without this declaration, it was because It not alerted my self